# Tool to email an alert when jvm memory hits a threshold?

Tags: memory, profiling, tomcat6, permgen

I'm after a good open source tool to email an alert when jvm memory hits a threshold.

I have applications sitting on Tomcat6.0 and occasionally the PermGen space used increases unexpectedly.  I would like to receive an alert when this occurs.  Using VisualVM I can see  that the usage is level most of the time so if it passes a certain threshold I know something is wrong.

Is there a good, open-source tool for emailing alerts when jvm memory hits a configurable threshold ?